# Can Jasmine tests be executed in a specific order?

Tags: protractor, jasmine

I believe it is considered to be a bad practice to rely on the order in which the (acceptance) tests should be run, but for testing "deeply nested features" (I don't know if there is a standard term for that) it might help to save time (I mean to save the time of repeating the same set of operations before each test; what I have in mind are actually Protractor tests).

So my question is whether there is a standard reliable way to fix the order in which Jasmine tests are perfomed.

Answer (score 6):

On Jasmine 3.x, [random order is the default behavior](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/927).

To run in order file written order, you can specify `--random=false` or use a seed.

Docs: https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.3/Configuration.html

Comment: This is super helpful. I was wondering why my tests are failing and thought random ordering is the reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the karma.config file to change the default randomization to false. I got the answer from the following blog:
https://www.miguoliang.com/how-to-fix-testing-order-in-angular-with-jasmine.html

Comment: That link goes to a 404. That's why it's best to provide the info in the post, because links can change.